# Iterate numbers within an fprintf

Tags: matlab

I have the following code in MATLAB. I want to iterate numbers 1, 2, and 3 sequentially in the `filename(%d)` section of the code such that if I turn on all tracks, each `if` statement will print `filename(1)`, `filename(2)`, `filename(3)`. If I turn off `B_track`, `A_track` will print `filename(1)` and `C_track` will print `filename(2)`. How can I iterate numbers within an fprintf so that filename(%d) prints out sequentially based on the tracks I turn on and off?

```
A_track = 1;
B_track = 0;
C_track = 1;

fid=fopen('test.txt','w');

if A_track ==1, i=1;
    fprintf(fid,'\n\n');
    fprintf(fid,['  filename(%d)=''test1''  \n'],i);
    fprintf(fid,'  idtrack(%d)=A_track \n',i);
end

if B_track ==1, i=2;
    fprintf(fid,'\n\n');
    fprintf(fid,['  filename(%d)=''test2''  \n'],i);
    fprintf(fid,'  idtrack(%d)=B_track \n',i);
end

if C_track ==1, i=3;
    fprintf(fid,'\n\n');
    fprintf(fid,['  filename(%d)=''test3''  \n'],i);
    fprintf(fid,'  idtrack(%d)=C_track \n',i);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Comment: How can I iterate numbers within an fprintf so that filename(%d) prints out sequentially based on the tracks I turn on and off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iteration of numbers the easiest trick is to use the [*mod()*](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) function. 
You set the divider and that sets the size of the list you want to iterate over.
As *mod()* will return 0 you have to add 1 to it, as matlab indexes matrices starting at 1 and not 0. (most programming languages start at 0)

So let's say you have a for loop and you want to iterate over the numbers 1, 2 and 3. Then it would look something like this

```
for ii=0:10
    nmbtoprint=mod(ii,3)+1;
    fprintf(fid,['  filename=''test_%1''  \n'],nmbtoprint);
end
```

You don't need to use a for loop for every if statement as long as you have a general counter. For a general counter you can create any variable and just make sure that it updates (adds 1 wherever you need it to in the script).

```
i=1; %number at which you initiate your variable

if %check if true then do something 
    %run some piece of code
    i=i+1; %increase the counter by 1
end
```

Also you can use a (cell) array.

```
idtoprint1=[0,1,10,100];
idtoprint2={'first','B','3rd'};

for ii=0:10
    ida1=mod(ii,4)+1;
    ida2=mod(ii,3)+1;
    fprintf(fid,['  filename=''test_%i''  \n'],idtoprint1(ida1));
    fprintf(fid,['  filename=''test_%s''  \n'],idtoprint2{ida2});
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you intend to accomplish: `i` is set to 1 at the start, and for every item printed out, it is incremented by one. This way, no matter which tracks are on or off, the ones that are on will print with a sequential `i`.

```
A_track = 1;
B_track = 0;
C_track = 1;

fid = fopen('test.txt','w');

i = 1;

if A_track
    fprintf(fid,'\n\n');
    fprintf(fid,['  filename(%d)=''test1''  \n'],i);
    fprintf(fid,'  idtrack(%d)=A_track \n',i);
    i = i+1;
end

if B_track
    fprintf(fid,'\n\n');
    fprintf(fid,['  filename(%d)=''test2''  \n'],i);
    fprintf(fid,'  idtrack(%d)=B_track \n',i);
    i = i+1;
end

if C_track
    fprintf(fid,'\n\n');
    fprintf(fid,['  filename(%d)=''test3''  \n'],i);
    fprintf(fid,'  idtrack(%d)=C_track \n',i);
    i = i+1;
end

fclose(fid);
```

I also changed your `if A_track==1` to `if A_track`. I find this easier to read. You can use `true` and `false` values to define each of the `track` variables, if that makes more sense to you. But `true` and `1` are identical for all purposes.